# how do I transfer data from an activity to a fragment?

Tags: android

I've tried a bunch of options, but not one has helped. They often talk about the method using bundle. I tried it, but nothing worked.

In activity:

```
String nameDictionary = dictionaryName;

Fragment fragment = new DictionariesFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("name", nameDictionary);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_fragment_one, fragment).commit();
```

in fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    textView.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
}
```

But the text doesn't change

Perhaps an important detail is that my fragment is located in the Navigation View, that is, in the side panel, which in turn is located in another activity.

I tried transmitting data through the interface, but that didn't work either

Comment: yes, I use it in onCreateView

Comment: I think there is no error in the code you showed us. The error must be in the code you didn't show us. Start the debugger to see what's wrong. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: in bundle, the value is always null. why?

Comment: What does bundle.containsKey("name") return? true or false?

Comment: how can I find out if bundle returns null? when calling this method, the program simply crashes